# Ошибка тестов Molecule

Tags: ansible

Собственно ошибка

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full
>   traceback, use -vvv. The error was: subprocess.CalledProcessError:
>   Command '['/usr/bin/vagrant', 'status', '--machine-readable', 'xen']'
>   returned non-zero exit status 1
>
> failed: [localhost] (item={'box': u'ubuntu/xenial64', 'name': u'xen'}) => {"changed": false, "item": {"box": "ubuntu/xenial64",
>   "name": "xen"}, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n
>   File \"/tmp/ansible_aiIM9Y/ansible_module_molecule_vagrant.py\", line
>   476, in \n    main()\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_aiIM9Y/ansible_module_molecule_vagrant.py\", line 469,
>   in main\n    v.up()\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_aiIM9Y/ansible_module_molecule_vagrant.py\", line 334,
>   in up\n    cd = self._created()\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_aiIM9Y/ansible_module_molecule_vagrant.py\", line 369,
>   in _created\n    status = self._status()\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_aiIM9Y/ansible_module_molecule_vagrant.py\", line 364,
>   in _status\n    s = self._vagrant.status(vm_name=instance_name)[0]\n 
>   File
>   \"/home/nikolay/work/ansible-role-redis/.ansible/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vagrant/**init**.py\",
>   line 493, in status\n    output = self._run_vagrant_command(['status',
>   '--machine-readable', vm_name])\n  File
>   \"/home/nikolay/work/ansible-role-redis/.ansible/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vagrant/**init**.py\",
>   line 976, in _run_vagrant_command\n    env=self.env, stderr=err_fh))\n
>   File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py\", line 574, in check_output\n
>   raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd,
>   output=output)\nsubprocess.CalledProcessError: Command
>   '['/usr/bin/vagrant', 'status', '--machine-readable', 'xen']' returned
>   non-zero exit status 1\n", "module_stdout": "--> Validating schema
>   /home/nikolay/work/ansible-role-redis/molecule/default/molecule.yml.\nValidation
>   completed successfully.\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}

Файлы для молекулы скопированы из другой роли, и на момент написания то роли, были рабочими.

Полез проверить другие тесты, там тоже самое. Полагаю проблема в новой версии молекулы или ансибла..

Если кто то объяснит, что изменилось и что подправить, буду признателен.

Comment: Добавьте контекста. Например, сценарии молекулы 1.х не совместимы с 2.х.

Comment: molecule, version 2.12.1;
ansible 2.5.0;
Vagrant 1.8.1. Написано все под 2 молекулу.